# Cannot run the Spring,Hibernate,Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

[image]

I get this error message when I tried to run the project. Can someone help me with a solution or else is any way to find the reason for this error?

Comment: Can you please click on the details button to show the logs?

Comment: Better start checking is server port is open and getting used by any other app.

Comment: @PraveenKumarKrishnaiyer When I click the details button it displays the message in the below text box "Server J2EE Preview at localhost failed to start."

Comment: @Mr.Arjun Could you please tell me how to check the server port. I have tried to find way to do that but couldn't find a good resource. Thank you in advance

Comment: did you check the log view? anything there?? You can use TCPview to get tcp communication insights

Comment: @Mr.Arjun yes errors are "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator", "An exception occurred invoking extension: org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.nestedproject.content for object F/CRUDWebAppMavenized/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources","Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!" . Could you please help me solve these errors

Comment: I'll be pleased to help! Kindly edit the question and add the whole error log there!

Comment: @Mr.Arjun Thank you very much for your response. I had the error in J2EE server. When I changed the server to Tomcat 7.0 the problem solved.